# 'float' object is not subscriptable error whehn shifting odeint to solve_ivp solver

Tags: ode, solver, odeint

When I successfully ran the simulation by using odeint solver. But when I tried to use solve_ivp solver, it gives me an error as "'float' object is not subscriptable". Can someone help me to solve with this issue?. Highly appreciate if you can show the corrected codings to solve the problem as I am bit new to advance coding.

```
    def tank(h,t):
    c1=0.13
    c2=0.20
    Ac=2.0
    qin=0.5
    h0=h[0]
    h1=h[1]

    qout1=c1*h0**0.5
    qout2=c2*h1**0.5
    dhdt1=(qin-qout1)/Ac
    dhdt2=(qout1-qout2)/Ac
    dhdt=[dhdt1,dhdt2]
    return dhdt
t0=0
tfinal=100
tspan=np.arange(0,tfinal+1)
y0=np.array([0,0])
# t=np.linspace(0,10,21)
# y=odeint(tank,y0,t,)
y=solve_ivp(tank,(t0,tfinal),y0,t_eval=tspan)

print(y)
plt.plot(t,y[:,0],'b-')
plt.plot(t,y[:,1],'r--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The argument order is different, odeint has (y,t), all others have (t,y), also odeint with tfirst=True.

Comment: I want to i simulate by using solver_ivp not odeint. Hope the order is correct with solver_ivp as you can see in the above code.

Comment: Look into the documentation for both, find what argument order is expected for the ODE system function. You can also not use the same `t`, as solve_ivp expects a time span using the first two numbers to define the interval. `t_eval` gets the times for the output. The output is also different, `res=solve_ivp(...)` has `res.t`, `res.y` for the function table of the solution.

Comment: I modified the code as you said.y=solve_ivp(tank,(t0,tfinal),y0,t_eval=tspan), But still the error is the same.

Comment: Yes, of course the error will be the same if you do not correct it. The scalar `t` does indeed not allow a subscript. The solver gives (t,y), you read (h,t), so the variable h has content t.

Comment: I am bit confused as I am new to coding. Be kind to provide the solution with correct code?.

Comment: Most directly, but least efficient, would be `res = solve_ivp(lambda t,h: tank(h,t), (t0,tfinal),y0,...)` to redirect the arguments into the correct order.

Comment: One more question: here it is easy to use a lambda function as it is a simple function. But what is the solution if I have to deal with many derivatives in the derivative function?.

Comment: It should work the same. Or it could be simpler to use `def tank(t,h):` and set the option `tfirst=True` in `odeint` (which implements such a redirection wrapper internally).